What is the best way to reliable unsubscribe someone with very dynamic emails and different campaigns in one journey?
Here’s the situation in short.
We have email series running for all kinds of series but when making those dynamic for different languages, we run into the problem making people unsubscribe without setting up specific automations.
We set up global campaigns and subcampaigns for each different language.
Say we’d make a series about practicing good habits.
We’d set up a parent campaign called ‘Good Habits (Global)’ with campaignId 1111. Other campaigns are under that and are called ‘Good Habits (EN)’ (Id 2222),‘Good Habits (ES)’ (Id 3333), etc.
We make a Journey (Good Habits Journey) that is triggered by Salesforce Data. We set it up the entry event to happen when someone is made a campaignMember and they will get into the journey if the parentId = 1111.
The emails are set up in a way our team members (non-It) can fill in the data through an external form which will go into a data extension. We include language in the Entry Data and that way the new subscribers will get the correct content based on their language.
When people unsubscribe, in Salesforce their status opt in will be set to ‘false’. Through an import of a report with the global campaign as a filter as well as things like ‘status opt in’, we can check if people are still in the list or not and set that as the exit criteria for the journey (contact18d == ‘null’). After the waiting time in a journey, people who are not in the list anymore will exit the journey.
We have different solutions with different products, but the problem with this one is:
The import runs daily, what if people unsubscribe when the import is already done but there’s still time left in the waiting activity? We don’t want to extend the waiting duration by a specific amount, because the series should work in every language at any time.
We now just take it for granted this sometimes happens and people get one email still, but one other solution is to just do a ‘raiseerror’ in the email by looking up if someone status opt in in our data extension that is synced with SF. The problem with this, is that it doesn’t make subscribers exit the journey properly, it just doesn’t send the email.
Our question is, are there any reliable ways to just have people unsubscribe from a campaign, while keeping everything dynamic and people subscribed to different campaigns (with that one parent campaign though).
To be very concrete: If one contact is in a data extension (that is linked in data designer) two times, can we check for one specific row for the exit criteria in the journey builder?
